VSCode background processes triggering SSO in Python code
I have a Python repo that I'm working on in VSCode.
The repo structure is like this:
main_repo
-- utils
---- client
------ my_client.py

my_client.py contains this code:
class CustomClient(DataClient):
    def __init__(self, client_type=None, lazy_init=False):
        self.client_type = client_type
        self._is_initialized = False  # Tracks whether initialization has occurred
        # Initialize eagerly if not lazy
        if lazy_init is False:
            self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        """Explicitly initialize the base class if lazy_init=True."""
        if not self._is_initialized:
            super().__init__(...)  # initialization logic
            self._is_initialized = True

    @staticmethod
    def SpecificClient(lazy_init=False):
        """Factory method to create a Client of a certain type."""
        return CustomClient(client_type="foo", lazy_init=lazy_init)

So, the idea is that I can create a client like this:
client = CustomClient.SpecificClient(lazy_init=True)
client.initialize()

The client initialization triggers a web page for SSO login, and the issue is that this is happening every time I save a file in the IDE.
So, I imagine there is some background process that is checking the code, goes through the client.initialize() calls and executes them upon saving.
I tried changing the initialize method to:
    def initialize(self):
        """Explicitly initialize the base class if lazy_init=True."""
        stack = inspect.stack()
        for frame in stack:
            if "pylint" in frame.filename or "mypy" in frame.filename:
                return
        if not self._is_initialized:
            super().__init__(...)  # initialization logic
            self._is_initialized = True


but it's still launching the SSO everytime.
I tried disabling the extensions, I left only the ones shown in this picture, but I still have this issue:

Any suggestions?

Linters typically do static analysis and do not execute code. That's not to say you don't have some extension that is doing something on save, but it would be very unexpected (by me) that any tool would run my code without my explicit request to do so.

Given that you're writing a web application, it seems more likely that you have a server running that picks up on the change in the code and reinitialises after a save. What is hosting your application?

@Grismar , I'm not writing a web application. My program runs locally, and needs to connect to a database, so it uses this client for that. The SSO is generally triggered when the client is initialized.
